# Line-of-Sight Angle on Sphere

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the angle (in degrees) between two latitude/longitude pairs, but with a twist.  Most calculations I see use the Great Circle / bearing method, but this does not seem correct for my need.

I am sitting at the following coords (for the sake of argument): 
Point A: 38.89755 -76.96362

I would like to watch tomorrow's NASA / Orbital rocket launch at: 
Point B: 37.83832 -74.51674

The rocket will rise over 10deg altitude from my place, so I should be able to see it well.

How do I calculate the direction that I should look in, assuming the rocket flies straight up (I know it won't, but perhaps the math is easier)?  I will be setting up a fair bit of astrophotography stuff and there are a few obstacles within a couple degrees of my target (126.83° according to Great Circle), so I would like to calculate it exactly to avoid them (I know my magnetic declination is currently -10.604, so I can add that later).

I understand that in many cases, a rocket launched straight up from Point B will never be visible from Point A since the paths never converge, so this makes the math slightly more frightening.

I've tried to calculate this in the past as well, where I grew up on one side of Lake Michigan and tried to imagine how tall a building on the other side (50 miles away) would need to be to be visible, and at what azimuth/altitude, but it seems to elude me.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand, but it seems to me that the direction in which you have to look lies somewhere in the plane determined by you, the launch point, and the center of the earth, in other words the vertical plane containing you and the launch point. This hits the earth’s surface along the great-circle path that you know how to compute, so that the azimuth is exactly what’s given by that method. The altitude is another issue.

Comment: Perhaps I've confused myself by reading things like this:
"In general, your current heading will vary as you follow a great circle path (orthodrome); the final heading will differ from the initial heading by varying degrees according to distance and latitude (if you were to go from say 35°N,45°E (≈ Baghdad) to 35°N,135°E (≈ Osaka), you would start on a heading of 60° and end up on a heading of 120°!)."
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Right...if you were travelling along the great circle, your heading would change during the trip. But it's still true that if you stood in Baghdad and wanted to look in the *direction* of Osaka, you'd look in the direction N $60^\circ$ E. From other locations on that path, looking towards Osaka would require looking in a different compass direction.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @John, you’re right on the mark. Imagine a great-circle path that starts on the equator, maybe in a NE direction, to hit the equator again at the antipode of the original point. One’s heading starts at $45^\circ$, and at the midpoint is due E, $90^\circ$, while at the end of the trip halfway round the world, you’re heading SE, $135^\circ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance to the horizon is

$$d=r\tan\left(\sec^{-1}\left(1+\frac{h}{r}\right)\right)$$

where

$$d=\text{distance to horizon}$$
$$h=\text{height of the observer}$$
$$r=\text{radius of the sphere (aprox 6378137m for the Earth)}$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+to+the+horizon

You need to calculate this twice - once for you and once for the rocket. If the sum of these is greater than the distance between you then you can see it (barring topography).